# jQuery Post Returns Object Object when submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I know this has been answered to some degree elsewhere but nothing I tried seemed to do the trick. I have never used jQuery for this (I always had something like Angular's $http to handle this) but I'm getting an Object Object where it should spit out the email info. I've included the code below.

```
    var email = $("#email").val();
    $.post("http://httpbin.org/post", email, function(email, status){
        console.log("Email: " + email + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `console.log(email)`

Comment: Try `function(data){ console.log('Email:' + data.email)}` as your success method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to you all. It helped me arrive at the answer. Which is:

```
      $.post("http://httpbin.org/post", { email: email } , function(data, status){
        console.log(data.form.email);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try using JSON.stringify() for your object as this returns the string representation which is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can replace plus `+` by comma `,`!

`var email = $("#email").val();
    $.post("http://httpbin.org/post", email, function(email, status){
        console.log("Email: ", email, "Status: ", status);
    });`

hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `$.post()` is:

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( response) {
    // here response contains the server response in it
});
```

In your case, if it is showing `Object Object`, means the response is a `JSON object`, so you have to parse it like:

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(data.email);
    console.log(data.status);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$.post is the shorthand of the $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: data,
     success: success,
     dataType: dataType
});
```

> If you add console.log(email), it will display the content in the object email

```
var email = $("#email").val();
$.post("https://httpbin.org/post", email, function(email, status){
    console.log("Email: " + email + "\nStatus: " + status);
    console.log(email);
});
```

[image]

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/